# SQL SERVER – Find Most Expensive Queries

Tags: sql-server, performance, performance-tuning

I am running the following script to find most expensive queries.

However I want to narrow it down to only queries ran on Saturday 18th October 2014
Is there any way to do this?

```
SELECT TOP 50 SUBSTRING(qt.TEXT, (qs.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
((CASE qs.statement_end_offset
WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(qt.TEXT)
ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2)+1),
qs.execution_count,
qs.total_logical_reads, qs.last_logical_reads,
qs.total_logical_writes, qs.last_logical_writes,
qs.total_worker_time,
qs.last_worker_time,
qs.total_elapsed_time/1000000 total_elapsed_time_in_S,
qs.last_elapsed_time/1000000 last_elapsed_time_in_S,
qs.last_execution_time,
qp.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) qt
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) qp
ORDER BY qs.total_logical_reads DESC -- logical reads
-- ORDER BY qs.total_logical_writes DESC -- logical writes
-- ORDER BY qs.total_worker_time DESC -- CPU time
```

ps I got this script from http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/05/14/sql-server-find-most-expensive-queries-using-dmv/

The server is SQL Express 2012

Comment: Extended events would be a better choice to track aggregates.

Comment: @yijayp any pointers on how I'd use extended events to do this?

Comment: Did you search? http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/tracking-expensive-queries-with-extended-events-in-sql-2008/

Answer (score 4):

No, the DMVs track aggregates, not individual executions, so you can't pinpoint things like that.

Want to drill in, you'll need to capture queries using [server-side trace](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/finding-the-causes-of-poor-performance-in-sql-server,-part-1/)*, [extended events](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/tracking-expensive-queries-with-extended-events-in-sql-2008/), [management data warehouse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677306.aspx) or one of many 3rd party monitoring tools. The latter cost money but, IMHO, you get what you pay for. We have one I could recommend...

`*` **Note**: *trace and profiler are deprecated, so it is highly recommended to use extended events going forward.*

Comment: Is there anyway I can reset the stats the DMVs use at the start of a day so I can then just look at them over that day?

Comment: Aaaron can you go ahead and recommend one.

Comment: Sure, you can clear out the procedure cache nightly using `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;` - just note that it will cause a performance hit the first time any of these folks run queries because the plans will have to be recompiled. As for recommendations, [SQL Sentry Performance Advisor](https://www.sqlsentry.com/products/performance-advisor/sql-server-performance). *Disclaimer: I work for SQL Sentry.*